# How to move between views in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to open a view on a button click rather than on clicking a Navigation Link, but all I can find on the internet is how to do it with a Navigation Link.  So how do you do it without?

Code:

```
@State var goToMainView = false
```

```
NavigationLink(destination: ContentView(),isActive: $goToMainView,label:{}).hidden()
Button(action: {
      goToMainView = true
      context.delete(goal)
      do {
            try context.save()
      } catch {
            print(error)
      }
}, label: {
      Text("Delete Goal")
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can navigate with a button by using `NavigationLink`

```
@State var goToSecondView = false 

NavigationView {
 VStack {
  NavigationLink(destination: SecondView(),isActive: $goToSecondView,
    label: { EmptyView() })
  }.hidden()

  Button(action : { goToSecondView = true } , label : { Text("Click On Me") })
 }
}
```

And for more details , I wrote this article , it may help you
[How to navigate with SwiftUI](https://medium.com/shoof-io/how-to-navigate-with-swiftui-92fa463d4591)

Comment: Thanks this helps a lot, however when I try to do this to go back a view, it opens up the previous view in a brand new detail view.  So how do I fix that and go back a view?

Comment: @EthanPervere can you provide some code of what you did exactly ?

Comment: I added the code where I delete something in CoreData, and then move off the page.

Comment: What's the reason for going to another `View` after that the `delete` is done ?  , Anyway if you need to refresh the page after going back to it , use `onAppear{}`